# 2560X1600 Device with 4K Monitor

Tags: 4k-resolution

I would like to connect my  2560X1600 Displayport laptop to a 4K monitor.

When selecting a 4K monitor (3840x2160), should I expect the the output to be scaled or a 2560X1600 subsection of the display to be driven?

If you have experience connecting a 2560X1600 device to a 4K monitor **please** weigh in with details (make / model of devices).

Comment: I'd expect that resolution not to be selectable at all. If it is, results are likely to be unpredictable.

Comment: The monitor may scale the input, display it in a subsection of the screen at native resolution, or the laptop may be unable to send video output. These are all determined by the hardware of your computer and the capabilities of the monitor. We cannot be more specific unless you provide us with the specific model numbers and hardware specs of the computer and monitor.